# Error coming while running gem5 in fs mode

Tags: gem5

I am trying to run gem5 in FS mode.

****build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --disk-image=file:///home/coep/gem5%202/full_system_images/aarch-system-201901106 --arm-image=/home/coep/gem5 2/full_system_images/aarch-system-201901106****

Error coming is as follows :
**Usage: fs.py [options]
fs.py: error: no such option: --arm-image**

please help me to solve this error.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

fs.py does not take any argument with the name "--arm-image". That's why you are getting this error. Check [Options.py](https://github.com/gem5/gem5/blob/stable/configs/common/Options.py#L421) for all arguments that you can provide to the fs.py.

Note: fs.py and se.py are not the standard scripts for fs or se simulation. These are just example scripts. In an ideal case, you should write your own script.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command as I use it and it works fine for me (for Simplicity, I list each part of the command in new line (not required)):

```
 ./build/ARM/gem5.opt
 configs/example/fs.py
--disk-image=/home/null/aarch64.img
--kernel=/home/binaries/vmlinux.vexpress_gem5_v1_64
--cpu-type=DerivO3CPU
--caches --l2cache --l1d_size=64kB --l1i_size=64kB --l2_size=1024kB
--mem-size=4GB
```

As it is clear, you should correctly set the paths to the disk image and the kernel files; any other arguments are not required.

**Note:** This command was tested on both ***develop*** and ***stable*** Gem5 branches, and it correctly worked.

Comment: Hello,I am done with run command for Gem5 in FS mode.Now i want to run my own binary file in FS mode will you please suggest the command i should add in the above command to run my own binary in FS mode.

Comment: The above command will start the Gem5 in FS mode, i.e., you have a complete platform with Linux OS. Therefore, you can run your binaries from the terminal just by typing ./binary. Before this step, you need to move all you programs you want to run, to the disk image.