# Gem5,computer architecture

Tags: gem5

I am trying to run gem5 in FS mode by using command as : **"build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --disk-image=/home/coep/gem5%202/full_system_images/aarch32-ubuntu-natty-headless.img --arm=/home/coep/gem5 2/full_system_images/vmlinux.arm.smp.fb.3.2/vmlinux.arm.smp.fb.3.2"**
and getting error as : **"Usage: fs.py [options] fs.py: error: option --arm-iset: invalid choice: '/home/coep/gem5' (choose from 'arm', 'thumb', 'aarch64')"**
please help me to solve this error.
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error coming while running gem5 in fs mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66328397/error-coming-while-running-gem5-in-fs-mode)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `--arm=/home/coep/gem5...vmlinux.arm.smp.fb.3.2` argument specifies the path to the guest kernel, in which case it should be `--kernel=...`:

```
build/ARM/gem5.opt \
configs/example/fs.py \
--disk-image=/home/coep/gem5\ 2/full_system_images/aarch32-ubuntu-natty-headless.img \
--kernel=/home/coep/gem5\ 2/full_system_images/vmlinux.arm.smp.fb.3.2/vmlinux.arm.smp.fb.3.2
```

Arguments and their explanations are found in `configs/common/Options.py`

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons why are getting this error, One of them can be an incorrect path to the disk image files.

I have run the gem5 in the FS mode and have booted Linux on top of it on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

You can follow the below steps, the first step is to download and install the full-system binary and disk image files.

```
 1. $ mkdir full_system_image
 2. $ cd full_system_image/
 3. $ wget http://www.m5sim.org/dist/current/arm/aarch-system-2014-10.tar.bz2
 4. $ tar jxf aarch-system-2014-10.tar.bz2
 5. $ echo "export M5_PATH=/Path to the full_system_image directory/full_system_images/" >> ~/.bashrc
 6. $ source ~/.bashrc
 7. $ echo $M5_PATH  (- check if the path is set correct)
```

Now the path has been set, the next step is to run the gem5 in FS mode.

```
 1. connect to gem5 base directory
 2. $ ./build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --disk-image=/home/full_system_image/disks/aarch32-ubuntu-natty-headless.img
 3. Note: --disk-image=path to the full_system_image/disks/aarch32-ubuntu-natty-headless.img
 4. open a new terminal and listen to port 3456 
 5. $ telnet localhost 3456
 6. Here 3456 is a port number on the gem5 terminal
 7. this will take around 30 mins depending on the machine performance.
 8. After this, at the end you will get something like this

    input: AT Raw Set 2 keyboard as /devices/smb.14/motherboard.15/iofpga.17/1c060000.kmi/serio0/input/input0
    input: touchkitPS/2 eGalax Touchscreen as 
    /devices/smb.14/motherboard.15/iofpga.17/1c070000.kmi/serio1/input/input2
    kjournald starting. Commit interval 5 seconds
    EXT3-fs (sda1): using internal journal
    EXT3-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with writeback data mode
    VFS: Mounted root (ext3 filesystem) on device 8:1.
    Freeing unused kernel memory: 292K (806aa000 - 806f3000)
    random: init urandom read with 14 bits of entropy available
    Ubuntu 11.04 gem5sim ttySA0

 9. login as root
```

Voila, you have run the gem5 in FS mode.